# deserialize nested object using objectMapper

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization, objectmapper

Here it goes a toy version of what I want to do.

I have a JSON in the following format.

```
{
    "id": "XXXXX",
    "url": null,
    "arrival":[       
     {
       "from": "13:00",
       "to": "14:00",
       "max": 100
     },
     {
       "from": "14:00",
       "to": "15:00",
       "max": 200
     }
   ]
}
```

Which is to be deserialized into

```
public class Information{

  private String id;

  private String url;

  private ClassContainingArrivals var; 

}
```

`ClassContainingArrivals` is the one having the field `List<HoursAndMax> arrival`, which in turn holds the information from "arrivals".

What I plan to do is adding the field `List<HoursAndMax> arrival` to `Information`, and pass it on to `var.arrival` later in the code, in order to `objectMapper.readValue` to work correctly.

Is there a way to tell `objectMapper` or annotate the field `var` so I can deserialize that JSON list straight into `var.arrival` instead of having to add that other field to `Information`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - @JsonUnwrapped.

```java
public class Information {
  public String id;

  public String url;

  @JsonUnwrapped
  public ClassContainingArrivals var; 
}
```